# Python API error (3.6)

Tags: python, api

I've recently started learning Python API's and I've run into a problem while trying to access the HaveIBeenPwned API. I can get it to print the JSON data so I think it's a formatting problem? All other solutions seem to force me to rewrite my entire code only to find it doesn't work anyway or is incompatible.

```
#This program aims to provide 4 search functions by which users can test if their data is at risk.
import urllib.request as url
import json
import ast

def UsernameSearch():
    print("Username search selected!")

def PasswordSearch():
    print("Password search selected!")

def EmailSearch():
    Username = input("Please enter the Email that's going to be searched \n: ")   

    def DataGetCurrent(Username):
        SearchURL = "https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/{}".format(Username)
        request = url.urlopen(url.Request(SearchURL, headers={'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0"}))
        data = request.read()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        json_data = json.loads(data)
        return json_data[0]

    Data = DataGetCurrent(Username)    
    a = ("Your Email address has been involved in [number] breaches: \nBreach \nTitle: {}\nWebsite: {}\nDate: {}\nInformation: {}\nLeaked Data: {}".format(Data['Title'],Data['Domain'],Data['BreachDate'],Data['Description'],Data['DataClasses']))
    print(a)

def SiteSearch():
    print("Website search selected!")

def loop():
    try:
        answer = input("There are currently 5 options: \n(1)Username search \n(2)Password search \n(3)Email search \n(4)Website search \n(5)Exit \n \n:")
        if answer.upper() == "1":
            UsernameSearch()
        elif answer.upper() == "2":
            PasswordSearch()
        elif answer.upper() == "3":
            EmailSearch()
        elif answer.upper() == "4":
            SiteSearch()
        else:
            print("\nThis is invalid, sorry. Please try again!\n")
            loop()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nYou don't need to exit the program this way, there's an exit option; just type \"exit\"!\n")
        loop()
loop()
```

The error it throws is:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Edit:
Updated now and it does call some information however it only calls the first dictionary entry whereas I need it to call as many as there are (and preferably have a count variable sometimes).

I'm also having trouble selecting the "DataClasses" entry and printing the individual entities within.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code here instead of giving a link to pastebin?

Comment: Additionally, which line throws the error? Can you post the full error?

Comment: Updated, and it's line 24:

Comment: `Data ` seems to be a string, not a dictionary or any other collection that takes 'strings' as an index...

Comment: I did try to use the ast module to convert it to a dictionary but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a json string to dictionary, use json module (standard library):

```
import json

data_str = '{"index" : 5}'
json_dict = json.loads(data_str)
```

In your example:

```
import json

# ...

def DataGetCurrent(Username):
    SearchURL = "https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/{}".format(Username)
    request = url.urlopen(url.Request(SearchURL, headers={'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0"}))
    data = request.read()
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)
```

EDIT

Apparently HaveIBeenPwned returns a list of dictionaries. Therefore, to get the results, you need to get the dictionary in the 0th index of the list:

```
def DataGetCurrent(Username):
    SearchURL = "https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/{}".format(Username)
    request = url.urlopen(url.Request(SearchURL, headers={'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0"}))
    data = request.read()
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
    json_list = json.loads(data)
    return json_list[0]
```

EDIT 2

0th element of the list is only one of the results. To process all the results, the list itself should be returned and used accordingly.

Comment: I'm getting the same type error. @eozd
Does it work if you test it yourself? because I remember testing json.loads(data) a while back and it didn't work, still doesn't.

Comment: Firstly thanks, so 2 problems now.
1) How do I call all items in one of the keys (DataClasses)
2) How would I call all entries in the response?

Comment: edited my original post, any help is appreciated. @eozd